# Problem with thread and initialization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I have a problem with my code.
I lunch the thread and this thread have a NSTimer.
I must remember a variabile location but when i repeat the method i reinitialize these and i lose the progress.
Can you help me?
Thanks

My code:(these isn't my very code but is the same situation. I want remeber the number of the i but when restart the methods the program reinitialize the i)

```
-(void)callDectectionMove:(Movement*)tempMovement{


    int i = 0;

    i++;

    if(i == 5)
      return;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeToCatch target:self selector:@selector(detectMovement) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];    
}




-(int)detectPositionMovement:(float)cordX:(float)cordY:(float)cordZ:(float)sensibility{


    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(callDectectionMove) toTarget:self withObject:tempMovement]; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i is defined as local callDectectionMove and very time you call callDectectionMove new i will be initialized.

on every call you want to make use of same i object then you have make use static int i.

Comment: now you have 
"int i = 0;"


write it as "static int i = 0;" -> in this case only first time the i is initialized 0.